# WPF ListView with CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

The main question? Why first column displaying without `CheckBox`?

[image]

Expected:

[image]

MainWindow:

```
namespace ListExperiment
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ListViewModel();
        }
    }
    public class ColumnDescriptor
    {
        public string HeaderText { get; set; }

        public string DisplayMember { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Items { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> Columns { get; private set; }

        public ListViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            Items.Add(new Employee { Document = 43, FirstName = "Jhon", LastName = "Jhons", Id = 1, IsChecked = true });
            Items.Add(new Employee { Document = 41233, FirstName = "Jhon", LastName = "Jhons", Id = 2, IsChecked = true });
            Items.Add(new Employee { Document = 4343123, FirstName = "Jhon", LastName = "Jhons", Id = 3, IsChecked = false });
            Items.Add(new Employee { Document = 44324233, FirstName = "Jhon", LastName = "Jhons", Id = 4, IsChecked = true });

            this.Columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
            {
                new ColumnDescriptor { Type="CheckBox" },
                new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "FirstName", DisplayMember = "FirstName", Type="Common" },
                new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "LastName", DisplayMember = "LastName", Type="Common" }
            };
        }
    }

    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isChecked;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return isChecked;
            }

            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int Document { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ListExperiment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListExperiment.TestPadWPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Chk_Field" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView local:GridViewColumns.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText" local:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                      local:GridViewColumns.ColumnsSource="{Binding Columns}">
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CustomControl:

```
namespace ListExperiment.TestPadWPF
{
    public static class GridViewColumns
    {
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static object GetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (object)obj.GetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ColumnsSource",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(GridViewColumns),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(
                    null,
                    ColumnsSourceChanged));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderTextMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        private static void ColumnsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gridView = obj as GridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                gridView.Columns.Clear();

                if (e.OldValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.OldValue);
                    if (view != null)
                        RemoveHandlers(gridView, view);
                }

                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        AddHandlers(gridView, view);
                        CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static IDictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>> _gridViewsByColumnsSource =
            new Dictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>>();

        private static List<GridView> GetGridViewsForColumnSource(ICollectionView columnSource)
        {
            List<GridView> gridViews;
            if (!_gridViewsByColumnsSource.TryGetValue(columnSource, out gridViews))
            {
                gridViews = new List<GridView>();
                _gridViewsByColumnsSource.Add(columnSource, gridViews);
            }
            return gridViews;
        }

        private static void AddHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Add(gridView);
            view.CollectionChanged += ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private static void CreateColumns(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            foreach (var item in view)
            {
                GridViewColumn column;
                if (((ColumnDescriptor)item).Type == "CheckBox")
                {
                    Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
                    DataTemplate s = (DataTemplate)window.FindResource("Chk_Field");
                    column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
                    column.CellTemplate = s;
                }
                else
                {
                    column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
                }
                gridView.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            view.CollectionChanged -= ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Remove(gridView);
        }

        private static void ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;
            var gridViews = GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view);
            if (gridViews == null || gridViews.Count == 0)
                return;

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        List<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = gridView.Columns[e.OldStartingIndex + i];
                            columns.Add(column);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = columns[i];
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = column;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        gridView.Columns.Clear();
                        CreateColumns(gridView, sender as ICollectionView);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
        {
            GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
            string headerTextMember = GetHeaderTextMember(gridView);
            string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMemberMember(gridView);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerTextMember))
            {
                column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as string;
                column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName);
            }
            return column;
        }

        private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (prop != null)
                    return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Edited:

Implementation that gaved expected result:

```
namespace ListExperiment.TestPadWPF
{
    public static class GridViewColumns
    {
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static object GetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (object)obj.GetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ColumnsSource",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(GridViewColumns),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(
                    null,
                    ColumnsSourceChanged));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderTextMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        private static void ColumnsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gridView = obj as GridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                gridView.Columns.Clear();

                if (e.OldValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.OldValue);
                    if (view != null)
                        RemoveHandlers(gridView, view);
                }

                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        AddHandlers(gridView, view);
                        CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static IDictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>> _gridViewsByColumnsSource =
            new Dictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>>();

        private static List<GridView> GetGridViewsForColumnSource(ICollectionView columnSource)
        {
            List<GridView> gridViews;
            if (!_gridViewsByColumnsSource.TryGetValue(columnSource, out gridViews))
            {
                gridViews = new List<GridView>();
                _gridViewsByColumnsSource.Add(columnSource, gridViews);
            }
            return gridViews;
        }

        private static void AddHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Add(gridView);
            view.CollectionChanged += ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private static void CreateColumns(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            foreach (var item in view)
            {
                GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
                gridView.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            view.CollectionChanged -= ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Remove(gridView);
        }

        private static void ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;
            var gridViews = GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view);
            if (gridViews == null || gridViews.Count == 0)
                return;

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        List<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = gridView.Columns[e.OldStartingIndex + i];
                            columns.Add(column);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = columns[i];
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = column;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        gridView.Columns.Clear();
                        CreateColumns(gridView, sender as ICollectionView);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
        {
            Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            DataTemplate CheckBoxTemplate = (DataTemplate)window.FindResource("Chk_Field");

            GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
            string headerTextMember = GetHeaderTextMember(gridView);
            string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMemberMember(gridView);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerTextMember))
            {
                column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as string;
                string columnType = ((ColumnDescriptor)columnSource).Type;
                switch (columnType)
                {
                    case "Common":
                        column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName);
                        break;
                    case "CheckBox":
                        column.CellTemplate = CheckBoxTemplate;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return column;
        }

        private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (prop != null)
                    return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your columns correctly, add this:

```
 this.Columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
        {
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "IsChecked", DisplayMember = "IsChecked",Type="CheckBox" },
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "FirstName", DisplayMember = "FirstName", Type="Common" },
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "LastName", DisplayMember = "LastName", Type="Common" }
        };
```

The way you did it returned null when you call GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember) and it can't bind.

Comment: it's do not display checkbox with your suggestion.